# Рекурсивное обновление словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, словари

Имеются два словаря, разного уровня вложенности:

```
a1 = {1: {'a': 45, 'b': {'ff': 23, 'dd': 90}}}

a2 = {1:{'a': 45, 'b': {'f': 243, 'd': 90}}, 2: '23'}
```

Получить хочу следующее:

```
a3 = {1:{'a':45, 'b':{'ff': 23, 'dd': 90, 'f': 243,'d': 90}}, 2: '23'}
```

То есть объединить их. Что-типа `d1.update(d2)` или `{**d1, **d2}` только, чтобы учитывались также уровни вложенности. 
Понятно, что можно написать функцию рекурсивную. Но может есть что-нибудь поизящнее?

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то [писал алгоритм для таких целей](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c4ef2f1636f7d75b87807e858ea1eea6116df773/jsonmerge.py#L44):

```
def dict_merge(j1, j2):
    for k, v in j2.items():
        if k in j1 and isinstance(j1[k], dict) and isinstance(v, dict):
            dict_merge(j1[k], v)
        else:
            j1[k] = v
```

Проверка:

```
a1 = {1: {'a': 45, 'b': {'ff': 23, 'dd': 90}}}
a2 = {1: {'a': 45, 'b': {'f': 243, 'd': 90}}, 2: '23'}

a3 = {1: {'a':45, 'b':{'ff': 23, 'dd': 90, 'f': 243,'d': 90}}, 2: '23'}

dict_merge(a1, a2)
print(a1)
# {1: {'a': 45, 'b': {'ff': 23, 'dd': 90, 'f': 243, 'd': 90}}, 2: '23'}

print(a1 == a3)
# True
```

Comment: Это рекурсивно. Тут скорее вопрос, существует ли какой-нибудь иной способ, поизящнее что-ли.

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян, а вы спрашивали про изящные способы, а что может быть изящнее рекурсии? :D Не знаю, другого способа, циклы тут не помогут -- т.к. мы не знаем глубины вложенности. И, думаю, если и есть решения то они все на рекурсии

Comment: Как по мне - так очень красивое решение. У меня вообще полотно вышло ) Не стал выкладывать)

Comment: Хотел что-нибудь из встроенных библиотек.